# Can academic subjects be used as adjectives?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> **He is our chemistry teacher. 
>   He is our English teacher**.

etc? Can academic subjects be used as adjectives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of nouns can be used as adjectives; the grammatical term for this is ***noun adjunct***, and it happens when a noun modifies another noun.

You can read all about them on the [Wikipedia website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (notice how I just used *Wikipedia* as an adjective there); other examples include: *chicken soup, kitchen sink, light switch, brick house, biology teacher*, and *college professor.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. The position that the teacher holds is "chemistry teacher" or "English teacher", so referring to them as such is grammatically correct.

Comment: Your answer is correct but your reason is irrelevant – at least from a grammatical perspective.

Comment: But I think there is a chance of misunderstanding in case of linguistic subjects. For example English teacher can be misunderstood as 'a teacher of British descent '. In addition to this all the dictionaries list academic subjects as nouns but constructions like chemistry teacher, math teacher are quite common.